Animating width without stretching using CSS
I've been working on a "slider" element. It's mostly finished - but I'm still having some issues with animations.
It works as expected, but I am experiencing two issues:

Upon clicking on an element, the title is displayed immediately. I've already tried adding delays to the "div" element, but it doesn't seem to help. Am I missing anything?
The image gets stretched on transition, and I'd like to avoid that. I've found solutions using clipping and transforms, but if I just reveal the image using transforms, the original "width" is still taken. By setting width to 0, I eliminate that problem.



.nav .nav-link {
    position: relative;
    padding: 0;
    background: #1A5E3B;
    color: #fff;
    width: 40px;
    height: 375px;
    transition: all 2s;
}

.nav .nav-link div {
    writing-mode: tb-rl;
    transform: rotate(-180deg);
    height: 100%;
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 1rem;
    font-weight: 600;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
}

.nav .nav-link img {
    width: 0;
    height: 375px;
    transition: width 2s;
}

.nav .nav-link.active {
    width: 250px;
  color: #fff;
}

.nav .nav-link.active div {
    writing-mode: initial;
    transform: initial;
    position: absolute;
    top: initial;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 20%;
    display: block;
    background: linear-gradient(to left bottom, #51874CB3 0%, #1A5E3BFF 100%);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.nav .nav-link.active img {
    width: 250px;
}
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/5.3.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/5.0.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="nav">
   <a class="nav-link m-1 active" data-bs-toggle="tab" href="#tab1">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/250/375?q=111" class="img-fluid" alt="Gozdnogospodarsko načrtovanje">
      <div>TEST 1</div>
   </a>
   <a class="nav-link m-1" data-bs-toggle="tab" href="#tab2">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/250/375?q=222" class="img-fluid" alt="Gojenje gozdov">
      <div>TEST 2</div>
   </a>
   <a class="nav-link m-1" data-bs-toggle="tab" href="#tab3">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/250/375?q=333" class="img-fluid" alt="Varstvo gozdov">
      <div>TEST 3</div>
   </a>
   <a class="nav-link m-1" data-bs-toggle="tab" href="#tab3">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/250/375?q=444" class="img-fluid" alt="Varstvo gozdov">
      <div>TEST 4</div>
   </a>
   <a class="nav-link m-1" data-bs-toggle="tab" href="#tab3">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/250/375?q=555" class="img-fluid" alt="Varstvo gozdov">
      <div>TEST 5</div>
   </a>
   <a class="nav-link m-1" data-bs-toggle="tab" href="#tab3">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/250/375?q=666" class="img-fluid" alt="Varstvo gozdov">
      <div>TEST 6</div>
   </a>
   <a class="nav-link m-1" data-bs-toggle="tab" href="#tab3">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/250/375?q=777" class="img-fluid" alt="Varstvo gozdov">
      <div>TEST 7</div>
   </a>
</div>




I think you should try adding images as background images. - https://codepen.io/cwaldo/pen/XYBxLP

@ChamiM that worked for no stretching! :)
Any clue how to transition the bottom absolute position boxes (on active elements) to slide in/out from the bottom? I'm transitioning from height 100%, so I don't think it's even possible?

do you have an updated code? put it in a codepen if you have. let me try to see what's the problem

@ChamiM yes! CSS is a bit messy, since I am compiling from SASS.
https://codepen.io/excav/pen/vYwdjqV
It works perfectly, only thing I would like is animating the "active" title up and down, and when transitions happen, I don't want the image to dissapear instantly - I want the image to "close" at the same time as the new one "opens".

I'm not sure whether this is the solution you are looking for but try it anyway @Matic - https://codepen.io/excav/pen/vYwdjqV

@ChamiM I'm not seeing any changes - you sure it's the right URL?

Sorry I updated the link - https://codepen.io/aroshm/pen/rNgJrPE

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

Add object-fit: cover; to your .nav .nav-link img-selector and remove the zero width. Should work right away.
